# Div's height gets extended but items appear out of div's workspace

Tags: css, html, extjs, panel

I want to do this simple task. I have the following code for `div` and ExtJS `panel`. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CHUrB/306/)**

```
#drawing 
{
    position: absolute;
    border: solid 2px green;
    width:    100%;
    height:   300
}
```

and

```
var contentPanel =  Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', 
{
     title: '',
     region: 'center',
     margins: '2 0 0 0',
     border: false,
     autoScroll: true,
     contentEl: 'drawing',
});
```

After the views are created, everything is rendered, I am calling some **JS** function that is supposed to resize **div**'s height based on some condition.

I have **`yCoord`** variable that gets incremented within the program and once it has reached the height of **`contentPanel`**, I want to extents it's div's height with the following code:

```
if (yCoord > contentPanel.getHeight() - 200)
{
    document.getElementById('drawing').setAttribute("style", "height:"+ (2*yCoord) + "px"); 
}
```

Simple, right?

But this is what I am having problem with... 
Once the height is set, I can see the vertical scroll bar extended on the panel, "meaning that the workspace has been extended". **But when you click 4rd time, the rect goes out of workspace. Why?**

Comment: Your JSFiddle is not functional. Please update it to be functional.

Comment: it is working, just click on "clickme"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to resize your Raphael's canvas:

`p.setSize('100%', 2*yCoord+contentPanel.getHeight());`